# Detect when DataGrid have and dont have content

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, icollectionview

I want to Bind a Button IsEnabled property to DataGrid property/Event when it has a Content.
The DataGrid's Item Source is an Observable collection but Since I implement Filtering, what is displayed can be different from the ItemSource collection.

Is there an event or Property of DataGrid that gets fired when the View is empty or not empty?

Comment: even though you use Observable collection and implement Filtering, you can get the collection's count.binding it with Button's IsEnabled property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a simple example could be made using `HasItems` property from DataGrid's base class `ItemsControl`

HasItems counts only displayable rows after any filter

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dGrid">
        an item
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="a button"
            IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems,ElementName=dGrid}" />
</StackPanel>
```

so the HasItems from DataGrid will determine if the Button is enabled or not